# Character.getNumericValue() issue

Tags: java, char, character

I'm probably missing something, but why are the two numeric values equal to `-1`?

```
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(Character.MAX_VALUE));
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(Character.MIN_VALUE));
```

Returns:

```
-1
-1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getNumericValue()` will convert characters that actually represent numbers (like the "normal" digits 0-9, but also numerals in other scripts) to their numeric value. The Characters represented by `Character.MAX_VALUE`and `Character.MIN_VALUE` do not have such a numeric value; they are not numerals. And according to the [API doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)):

> If the character does not have a
>   numeric value, then -1 is returned.

Answer (score 6):

`getNumericValue()` only applies to characters that represent numbers, such as the digits `'0'` through `'9'`.  As a convenience, it also treats the ASCII letters as if they were digits in a base-36 number system (so `'A'` is 10 and `'Z'` is 35).

This one fools a lot of people.  If you want to know the *Unicode* value of a character, all you have to do is cast it to `int`:

```
System.out.println((int)Character.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println((int)Character.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `Character.MAX_VALUE` and `Character.MIN_VALUE` aren't numeric.  [Character.getNumericValue(char)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) returns -1 when the parameter isn't a character that maps to a number.

Number characters (0-9), letter characters (A-Z), and other unicode number characters are associated with values.  I don't know all the other characters that are mapped.  But many characters will just return -1.

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect; there are many more characters that have associated numerical values defined by the Unicode standard.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that.  I guess they just give roman numerals as 1 example in the method documentation.

Answer (score 3):

.. just because `\u0000` and '\uffff` don't represent a digit and don't have a numeric value.

I guess you were looking for the 16bit value of the char, but for this we can simply cast:

```
int value = (int) Character.MAX_VALUE;
```